# F# function return several types (return kind of generic object type)?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I keep learning F# pattern matching with my simple function which should return square root if argument is number, argument otherwise. I've modified it a bit and it looks like as follows.

```
let my_sqrt (o: obj) =
  match o with
  | :? float as d -> (sqrt d).ToString()
  | _ as x -> x.ToString()
```

It is working fine for my purpose, but what if I don't want to cast return value to string? How can I return "some object" and then use it in `printfn "%A" (my_sqrt [| 1; 2; 3 |])` construction?

Comment: If I may ask, what's the purpose of returning the argument unchanged if it is not a float? In which situation would that be useful?

Comment: Just wrote example of function which return different types to show what I want to know :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want

```
let my_sqrt (o: obj) =
  match o with
  | :? float as d -> (sqrt d) :> obj
  | _ as x -> x
```

just upcast to object

Answer (score 8):

Even though your example is just a demonstration of what you're trying to do, it is worth pointing out that this is probably not a good design. In F#, you would not normally use functions that operate on objects using casts - a better way to represent this would be a discriminated union:

```
type MyInput = 
  | Numeric of float
  | Other of obj

let my_sqrt = function
  | Numeric d -> Numeric (sqrt d)
  | Other o -> Other o
```

This function works on a type that is either `Numeric` or `Other`, but thanks to the DU, you do not need any casting. I think something along these lines would be a better approach to your actual problem too.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I'm new to F# and to strong types in general, so this looks a bit confusing for me. We define kind of set of types, define function which works with its subtypes, but what purpose on wrapping return values of this function? To show that function gets MyInput and returns MyInput?

Comment: @dig The idea is that you should be explicit about what the function returns - if you have a function `obj -> obj`, you are saying that it can take anything and return anything. The purpose of `MyInput` is to say that the function takes either `float` (in which case it does something special) or anything else. I wrapped the return value in the same type, because I suspected that you might want to distinguish between the two cases after calling the function too.

Comment: @dig But I think it is difficult to give a useful answer without knowing more about the specific use that you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is ok. When you want to compute each square root, you have to map your function over array like this:

```
Array.map my_sqrt [| 1.0; 2.0; 3.0 |] |> printfn "%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in TP answer, the general idea should be, wherever possible, to surface information to your type system.

- It is then ***easier*** for you to read and reason your program, as you have **named** things.
- That means F# can actually **work for you** and tell you when you made something wrong

That makes it always worth the investment.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tomas that using a Discriminated Union would be better. There is no Either monad built into F# but you could use the Choice union to standardize the interface:

```
let my_sqrt (o : obj) = 
  match o with 
  | :? float as d -> Choice1Of2 (sqrt d) 
  | o -> Choice2Of2 o;;
```